# c++: copy, delete and operator = in map of raw pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, copy, smart-pointers

I have a question related to smart pointers and raw pointers.

My first idea was work with raw pointers: so if in a class (e.g. class Routes) its attributes are `map<string, list<Route *>> _mapIATA` and `map<int, list<Route*>> _mapID`, I will have to implement in the class a destroyer, a copy and a operator= methods, am I wrong?

However, if instead of using raw pointers, I used smart pointers I would not have to worry about deleting the content pointed, but what about copying and assigning?

At the moment though, I am not sure about what would be better; raw or smart pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: The overhead of `std::unique_ptr` is probably less compared to a raw pointer. Copying and assigning can probably be prevented with using in-place construction of nodes e.g. with [`std::list<T,Allocator>::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back).

Comment: Concerning the map of list of something, [`std::multi_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) might be an alternative as well.

Comment: I did think about using a multi_map but for the purpose of the program is better work with a map and a list on it.

Comment: Somewhere you wrote _I would copy the same Route maybe 20 times..._. Does it mean the same instance of `Route` can appear in multiple `map` entries, maybe, even multiple times in one list? In this case, I would prefer a `std::shared_ptr` (regardless of its extra costs). I have fighted with too many never-stable-applications until I started to work with smart-pointers. Another solution (I tried before) could be a global vector (or map) for storage of all `Route`s and references by index (instead of raw pointers) allowing, at least, to detect lost instances...

Answer (score 5):

> I am working with a big amount of Data that's why I considered to use raw pointers,...

This is a false premise. A `std::list` does internally use dynamic memory. You gain nothing by adding another layer of indirection. Use pointers when you want to point to something. If you want objects use objects.

> However, if instead of using raw pointers, I used smart pointers I would not have to worry about deleting the content pointed, but what about copying and assigning?

Independent of using pointers or not you have to make sure you correctly implemented the [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

> I am not sure about what would be better; raw or smart pointers.

Neither. Use a `map<string, list<Route>>` unless you need the `Route`s to be shared among several owners (if you dont know what that means then probably no).

PS: If you worry about performance it might be worth to try `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

Comment: I have to use pointers, I know that for sure. And yeah, I do know I always have to implement a destructor, a copy and an assigment operator as well... My question is more based in if I used smart pointers, should I implement a copy and operator = methods? I hardly ever worked with them that's why I ask. If that's true, I will prefer to work with row pointers.

Comment: @LauraGalera "I have to use pointers, I know that for sure." why?

Comment: @LauraGalera whether you need to implement a copy/assignment etc is indepenedent of using pointers. As I wrote, you need to obey the rule of 0/3/5, smart pointers or not wont change that

Comment: because I have different classes that interact with Routes and Routes has not just 2 maps, more, I would copy the same Route maybe 20 times... not interested. About your advice of using a vector: not really, for me is more useful a list because the capacity of the vector would be too exaggerated and a list it's the best for me since all I must do is a push back of pointers (I am not interested in order)

Comment: Btw, when I said I am working with a big amount of Data I said it because a raw pointer means less space than a smart pointer (but that it's not a big difference anyway...) I was not doubting if I should use pointers and not objects.

Comment: @LauraGalera using raw pointers instead of objects will not result in less space in total. It will result in less performance due to more indirection. Also copying will not suffer since stuff can be moved. Uff thats quite some misunderstandings you have...my answer is still the same: Neither raw nor smart, but objects. You can have raw or smart pointers in containers, but the motivations are not to save space! (you need it eg when you want polymorphism or when ownership has to be shared)

Comment: @LauraGalera "I was not doubting if I should use pointers and not objects." ... and I tell you that you should doubt it ;)

Comment: @LauraGalera "using a vector: not really, for me is more useful a list because the capacity of the vector would be too exaggerated and a list it's the best for me since all I must do is a push back of pointers (I am not interested in order)" your argument of capacity is moot you can reserve any capacity you like when you dont like the powers of two growing . The main difference is the vectors data locality. Btw If you did use a vector, then the size of the elments would actaully matter and it would be worth to consider using smart pointers, for a list I dont see what you expect to gain

Comment: I know I could fix the capacity of the vector with resize I am afraid, but I think is more work than what I gain. Exactly, I was wondering if using smart pointers I would have to implement the assignment operator and the copy method (destroyer obviously not) and seems that yeah I should, then I will continue using raw pointers. That's the question I had.

Comment: Always that you do a great management of pointers you should have no problems. Basically they are one of the most powerful tools of c++.

Comment: @LauraGalera whether you need assignment or copy for your class is independent of using smart pointers or not

Comment: @LauraGalera I know how difficult it is, once having mastered the art manual memory managment via pointers, to realize that actually you dont need it. I am still puzzled what problem you solve by using pointers, but tbh I give up...

Comment: @LauraGalera btw it would have helped if you added some code to the question to illustrate the problem, because when deciding to use pointers or not without more context, the decision is simple: not